# My custom domain cannot point to nginx port 100, ipaddress:100 is working as intended.

Tags: nginx

my server block listens to port 100.  When I access my site with ipaddress:100 I can see the landing page.  However I am not able to point to this port to my domain.

```
server {
    listen  100;

    server_name mydomain.com;
```

}

When I type mydomain.com, I go the default port 80.  How can redirect  my domain to this specific port.

Comment: Are you saying that `mydomain.com:100` does not work?

Comment: mydomain.com:100 does woking, How do I invoke :100 port when I type the just the 'mydomain.com'.

Comment: It is not possible. HTTP is port 80. HTTPS is 443. If you require other port, you have to specify the number.

Comment: @TanHongTat . Thanks.